# How to call a function or method that is Namespaced using another plugin

Tags: filters, hooks, actions

I'm using an action from one plugin that needs to call a function from another plugin. That function is name spaced.

Typically, I would use something like:

```
add_action( 'hook_name', 'function_name' );
```

But the plugin's function is Namespaced and/or object-oriented, so I'm not sure how to reference the function in that case.

I.e., how do I reference that specific function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is generic code that worked for me. If anyone wants a real-life example, please let me know.

This creates a function that calls the plugin's function assuming the namespace is "Custom"

```
add_action( 'hook_name', 'my_custom_function_name' );
function my_custom_function_name() {
    // Check if "Custom Plugin" installed and activated
    if ( did_action( 'plugin/loaded' ) ) {
        // call the Plugin's function (clear_cache function example here)
        \Custom\Plugin::instance()->files_manager->clear_cache();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`add_action`'s second parameter is a `callable`, it can accept a string (like what you did in the example) or an array of class-instance and function name.

For example, if you want to call a method `get_age()` from `Person` class, you can do this:

```
$person = new Person();
add_action( 'hook_name', array($person , 'get_age') );
```

Comment: Your answer doesn't seem to reference another plugin. When I try it, it says Uncaught Error: Class 'Elementor' not found in /wp-content/mu-plugins/fd-clear-elementor-cache.php:21. Could you add more detail to your answer or use this as an example: https://code.elementor.com/methods/elementor-core-files-manager-clear_cache/

Comment: You should find a way to get the `Manager class` instance instead of instantiating using `new` keyword. If it is a static method, you can write it like this without instantiating the class `add_action('hook_name',array(Manager::class,'clear_cache'))`